# Email Template Logo always using the LUMA

Tags: magento2.2.3

I'm creating an email template, I already updated the transactional email logo. But still when I tested it always uses the default luma logo. I'm using Magento ver. 2.2.3

Comment: you got the solution!

Comment: @JmCabugnason you got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

To to get your theme logo,

1. First you need to enable your theme from admin
2. Then you are able to get your theme logo.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-change-email-logo-magento-2.html -- Try this one

Comment: I already enabled it, on the backend when the email template is previewed it will display the set transactional email logo, but on frontend the logo the is being used is the LUMA logo.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?  Or did you changed the permission?

Comment: Please  deploy to get effect .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Go to Admin

**Content > Design > Configuration**

https://www.screencast.com/t/Ccu8RkieMu6G

Answer (score 0):

In your theme check - Magento_Email\web. Check if your logo is there or Luma. If Luma logo is there then replace it with your logo.
If even that is not working then check the code from where you are triggering the email:
In setTemplateOptions Store should be proper, use storeManagerInterface to get the store id
->setTemplateOptions(
[
'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
]
)